# Utilizando String

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class String {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

          String cadena;

          System.out.println("Introcuce un nombre");
          cadena = sc.nextLine();

          System.out.println("Buenos dias "+cadena);

      }

}
```

¿Por qué  me dice el programa lo siguiente?

> String cannot be converted to string

Comment: Tu clase se llama String, la cual es una palabra reservada por java. Cambia el nombre de la clase

Comment: Ok poco a poco me va saliendo, gracias por responder

Answer (score 2):

Tu clase se llama igual que el tipo de dato `String`, por lo que el compilador piensa que cuando usas `String` dentro del main te estás  refiriendo a la clase,  mas no al tipo de dato.

No le pongas nombres de palabras reservadas o clases existentes en la API a tus clases.

Comment: He probado cambiando la clase por otro nombre pero sigue sin funcionar, puedes poner un codigo de ejemplo corregido?

Comment: Cambiando el nombre de tu clase **tiene** que funcionar porque no hay errores más  que eso. Recuerda que si cambias el nombre de la clase debes también cambiar el nombre del fichero.

Comment: @Carlos recuerda que si cambias el nombre de la clase, también debes cambiar el nombre del archivo. En Java, el nombre del archivo y de la clase pública deben ser el mismo.

Comment: ok si que funiona, gracias

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos problemas con el codigo uno es el parámetro de entrada en tu función main, ya que está utilizando tu clase String y no la que está definida en java por defecto, este mismo caso se repite con tu variable cadena, que trata de resolver con la clase que haz definido.

Para no modificar mucho tu código debería resolver el programa de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String {

    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        java.lang.String cadena;

        System.out.println("Introduce un nombre");
        cadena = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();

        System.out.println("Buenos días " + cadena);
    }
}
```

Pdta: No se te olvide cerrar tu objeto scanner.

Comment: Gracias, es correcto